# Can pickle juice hurt snakes?

Tags: snakes, reactivity

I just caught a black rat snake and all I had was an old pickle jar with small amount of juice slightly left over at the bottom. But the snake appeared to have curl up completely hiding or playing dead?

Comment: pickle juice do contain vinegar(an acid)so yes this can kill snakes,in addition to vinegar it contains salt and this is dangerous to snakes too.

Comment: How do i save the snake? Do I wash it off with water? Maybe I can save it.

Comment: Never mind it survived. It was not where I released it just a minute ago.

Comment: If the exposure was short, rinsing it off probably suffices. As for playing dead, some colubrid species do this, but it's very distinctive behaviour. Rolling on their back, mouth open, tongue outside, insisting on rolling to their back again when turned around.